# Avoid behind content to be seen on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a mui table with a sticky row, this is the css for the column

```
position: sticky;
left: 0;
background-color: white;
z-index: 20;
border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
```

With this the first row can be on top of the other rows when scrolling. But i want to add a hover with this conditions

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)
```

But when i do this when i hover on the row the other content can be seen
[image]

What can i do?

Comment: Don't apply that css to the sticky row.

Comment: it's necessary to make it sticky?

Comment: Use `E5E5E5` instead of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01)`

Comment: Yeah it need to be sticky so the first row stays when scolling for the content

Comment: @ksav yeah that work, i  used one a little lighter but that was the trick, thank you so much